# Looking for recommendations for Project and Change Management tools

Tags: pm-software, change-management

I'm currently researching software project management tools for a team of 12 developers. In addition to project management, we'd like to handle help desk tickets and a SOX compliant change management process. I've used Atlassian JIRA in the past (and loved it), but it was for a smaller team with simpler requirements.

Key features we're looking for:

Project Management

- Time tracking by task
- Multiple resources per project
- Allow requesters (users within our company) to track task progress, preferably without a user license (may be deal killer for JIRA since we have hundreds of users and JIRA requires a user license per login)

Help Desk

- Allow requesters (users within our company) to track task progress, preferably without a user license (may be deal killer for JIRA since we have hundreds of users and JIRA requires a user license per login)
- Escalate ticket if assigner does not respond within a certain time frame

Change Management

- Workflow that allows a request to be approved by multiple team members (Lead Dev, DBA, Dev Manager, Dept Manager of requester, etc)
- Audit trail that gives us SOX compliance

Has anyone successfully used a single product for software project management, help desk support tickets and change management? If not a single product, what do you use and why?

Comment: Software recommendations...

Comment: Software recommendations are always out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

Before choosing a software, you should ask yourself some questions. How big is your team? Who will manage the software? Who will host? What is your budget?.

If you are a small-mid size firm, more features in the long run become more of a hassle. The best thing is to keep it simple and straightforward (KISS). For that I recommend [Project Pier](http://www.projectpier.org), it is open source, so it is free, easy to install, and easy to use. Unfortunately it does not have all the features you require, but you could easily take it to a programmer and modify the software to your firm needs.
Google is your best friend when searching for tools and software.

Comment: Unfortunately there are thousands of Google results about hundreds of project management tools. That's more than I have time to wade through.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting feedback....write users vs. read-only.  Alvazan, Inc will have to incorporate that.  If you like this type of read status [Alvazan Demo Status](http://alvazan.com/demo) on a project by project basis, we would be able to do X write users per price and allow as many read only users as you like.  Either way, thanks for the feature idea!!!!!

Dean (http://blog.alvazan.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good project management tool that has a time tracking feature (I personally also think it's very helpful when apps have it), I'd recommend Kanban Tool https://kanbantool.com/ . I've used it for a while and in my opinion, it's even better than some most popular tools of this kind. I like that it can serve multiple purposes and is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I am working for Eylean and I think your problem seems like something that our tool can solve. Eylean is a very visual and simplistic tool to involve anyone in organization, especially when talking about non-IT employees. Eylean has everything from daily task management to time tracking.

You can find more at http://www.eylean.com

[image]